# page loading gets slower on using mysql blob data type

Tags: php

I have been building a dynamic Content Management application using PHP, JavaScript and a little AJAX.  I used the  MySQL medium blob data type for storing files.  I see my website loading slowly.  Is this because of the blob data type?

Comment: what are u storing inside the blob?

Comment: Even mysql support blob data type, i think you should not store file in database.

Comment: Please provide more details, so we can help you more.

Comment: I use my SQL blob data type to store images and pdf documents

Answer (score 0):

You can find already described answer on this below:-

User has already describe the concept in good way, please read this.

[What is difference between storing data in a blob, vs. storing a pointer to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435187/what-is-difference-between-storing-data-in-a-blob-vs-storing-a-pointer-to-a-fi)