# Optimizing a Directory Structure on the File System ( referenced through database )

Tags: database, hash, query-optimization, rdbms, file-organization

After searching around for a while regarding the consensus over how to handle multimedia content for website (using native fileSystem or Database blobs), mainly here:

[MySQL Binary Storage using BLOB VS OS File System: large files, large quantities, large problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654004/mysql-binary-storage-using-blob-vs-os-file-system-large-files-large-quantities)

I have decided that I will go with saving directly on the filesystem and putting path references in the database. I am basically developing a web application that will contain loads of images(mainly around `5MB` to `10MB`) and videos (mainly around `50MB` to `100MB`).

Can someone suggest me on what would be the best possible way to organize my photos and videos on the filesystem. The popular solution I learnt of was to hash out the files into various subdirectories.

I am not clear with the fact that why do we start using the basename of the file from the reverse side? I tried grouping of 2 characters of the file name (suppose same was done from the reverse side) and then creating the hierarchy tree of directories. I could not spot the difference in either case in the width or height of the directory tree.

And also, since there will be potentially a huge amount of photos and videos, what must be my priority, optimizing the height of the directory tree or the width of the directory tree?

Comment: Directory lookup speed depends on directory and size and directory caching.  Size (number of entries) because the first time a file is opened the directory has to be scanned. So if you can limit the number of directories and the number of directory entries required to do the first lookup that is a win.  Hashed directory names might be appropriate for this. Repeated searches should find the cached directory information. To save scanning time. On some systems, like Solaris. this is called  directory inode cache tuning tuning and involves system settings.

Comment: @jimmcnamara so should i work on creating the best possible solution for directory caching? as the cumulative size of all directories is not much under my control

Comment: Work on both.  Simple Example: A hash with good avalanche might let you create say 100  directories.  Good avalanche means the hash code will spread file pretty evenly across directories. So. Hash the name of the file into a decimal number (or some kind of string).  Use the first two characters of that number/string as a directory name.  Write the file into that directory.  In a way I'm guessing as to the actual use of your application.  As the number of entries in a directory goes up the scan time goes up as well. I am assuming you are given a correct file name to find.

Comment: Or simply save the filename in the database as: /directoryname/filename.

Comment: @jimmcnamara i was thinking of generating hash values for each file, and accordingly create a folder (and sub-folders like grouping 'n' number of characters). The database could simply contain the hash code and on requirement I could resolve the hash into a directory according to my own rules. Is it correct to think this way that I am basically not searching in the filesystem but in the database. And then directly using the resolved path to access the file for faster access?

Comment: That will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the game on this. But one solution (if it fits your use-case) could be file name hashing. It is a way to create an easily reproducible file path using the name of the file while also creating a well distributed directory structure. For example, you can use the bytes of the filename's hashcode as it's path:

```
String fileName = "cat.gif";
int hash = fileName.hashCode();
int mask = 255;
int firstDir = hash & mask;
int secondDir = (hash >> 8) & mask;
```

This would result in the path being:

```
/172/029/cat.gif
```

You can then find `cat.gif` in the directory structure by reproducing the algorithm.

Using HEX as the directory names would be as easy as converting the `int` values:

```
String path = new StringBuilder(File.separator)
        .append(String.format("%02x", firstDir))
        .append(File.separator)
        .append(String.format("%02x", secondDir)
        .toString();
```

Resulting in:

```
/AC/1D/cat.gif
```

I wrote and article about this a few years ago and recently moved it to Medium. It has a few more details and some sample code: [File Name Hashing: Creating a Hashed Directory Structure](https://medium.com/@michael.andrews/file-name-hashing-creating-a-hashed-directory-structure-eabb03aa4091). Hope this helps!