# How do you manage a large video database?

Tags: mysql, database, video

I have tried giving some id and just storing its title, path and the rest in a MySQL database. But This looks simple. Is there any robust way out there to do that. Thanks

Comment: "KISS = Keep it simple stupid!"  That is the best way to go with

Comment: is that the way to go ? you didn't answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. But...

basically there is two way to deal with "binary large objects".

- The first one is to store them is a so called [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) column in your DB.
- The second one, is, as you do it now, to store in the DB only "pointers" to the actual data on an external storage solution. Usually as "path" referencing files on your file-system..

Both solutions have pro and cons. Regarding performances, data migration, load balancing, and so on. This has already been discussed elsewhere on SO:

- [MySQL Binary Storage using BLOB VS OS File System: large files, large quantities, large problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654004/mysql-binary-storage-using-blob-vs-os-file-system-large-files-large-quantities)
- [When is using MySQL BLOB recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285857/when-is-using-mysql-blob-recommended)

Comment: thanks that was helpful. But you happen to know what big sites like youtube use?

Comment: Probably distributed key-value store

Comment: ... well in fact not necessary (?) http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture If I read well "BigTable" is used only for thumbnails. Video seems to be static files served by lighttpd.